# Writing a print statement to a text file

Tags: python, text-files, glob

I am trying to print all files with *.txt to a text file, the folder looks like this

\folder
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.csv

my python code looks like this:

```
import glob
for text in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    print text

file=open('output.txt', 'w')
file.write(text)
file.close()
```

after running this, i get in the idle window
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
but my output.txt only has file2.txt written in it.

I thought this would be a quick way of getting the results, is there a way i can force "text" in its entirety to the output file?

Comment: To redirect a `print` statement's output to your output file instead of the console, use `print >> file, text` _after_ you've opened it.

Comment: @martineau That's actually a deprecated style. For new code you should use the print function (on 2.x do `from __future__ import print_function`). Then use `print("stuff", file=outfile)`. On 3.x `print` is already a function.

Comment: @Keith: Yes, I know it's deprecated which is just a warning of future obsolesce. One subtly is that after you `__future__ import`, you then have to use the function instead of statement everywhere -- at least in that module, so I generally ignore its official status when writing Python 2 code and figure the 2to3 utility can fix things should the code I'm writing ever need to be converted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in fact putting the entire value of `text` in the output file; `text` just isn't what you think it is.

The only place that `text` gets assigned to is in the `for text in glob.glob('*.txt')` loop. After the loop, it'll remain as the *last* value that got assigned to it, ie `'file2.txt'`.

There are a few ways to approach what you want to do. If you were running your script from the command line rather than from IDLE, you could do something like (in Unix)

```
python my_script.py | tee output.txt
```

to copy all the output from your script to the file `output.txt` without having to do anything in your Python code at all other than normal `print`s.

You could also write it out directly instead of calling `print` as [suggested by Lattyware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13167904/344821), though this won't do both unless you manually do both.

To make that a little easier, you could write a function to call instead of `print` that does both more conveniently. Something like:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    def my_print(str):
        print str
        f.write(str + '\n')

    for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        my_print(filename)
```

You could also do something a little fancier if you really wanted to use `print` statements: reassign [`sys.stdout`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout), the special object that does all the printing from Python. This is probably more complicated than you need, but if you want to see it ask and I'll show you.

Comment: Presuming you have access to a good shell that'll do it. That said, it is the simplest solution (although note that you would want to remove the python-side writing to the file).

Comment: The first method is by far the most unique answer, I am using python 2.6 on windows so I am unable to try it out.  As for your code and Lattyware, you both use with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:  and as explained I will try using this method for future coding attempts.  Thanks for the thorough explanation, I will try reading up on the sys.stdout

Answer (score 4):

`print()` only outputs to the console, nothing more. If you want to write to the file, then just do that.

You need to write the data inside the loop, otherwise you will only write the last value of `text`:

```
import glob

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        file.write(filename+'\n')
```

Do note the newlines I have added, as `file.write()` will not do that by default. You could naturally do your `print()` as well if you wanted it. Another option would have been to build up a list and then write the list of items to the file, but that is a little roundabout.

Note my use of the `with` statement to open a file, this closes the file for you, and does so even on exceptions, so it's good practice to keep your code more readable and thorough.

Comment: But you can now do this: `from __future__ import print_function; print(ob, file=myfile)`. The print function can print to any stream given by the `file` option.

Comment: I would argue that is less clear. If I see ``print()``, I'm expecting stdout, ``file.write()`` - on the other hand - makes it extremely clear what is going on.

Comment: However, the print function IS the future direction of Python. So more people will get used to seeing it used this way and not necessarily expect stdout in the future. Also, `print` handles string conversion and handles proper cross-platform line-endings for you whereas your file.write(obj) will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it using modern Python.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import glob

with open("output.txt", "w") as fo:
    for name in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        print(name, file=fo)
```

This puts the loop in the context manager and uses the forward-compatible print function.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the solutions already presented rightly involve using a `file`'s `write` method, so here's an alternate take, using only `print`.

The `print` statement (/!\ python 2.x) offers an easy way to write to a file:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    print >> f, 'StuffToWrite'
```

Or you could replace `sys.stdout` with your file:

```
import sys
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f
    print 'StuffToWrite'
```

For reference, you can always get back your terminal's original `stdout` at `sys.__stdout__`.

---

Let me however insist on the fact that these are quick and dirty solutions.
The main advantage is that you **don't have to bother what you try to write not being compatible with `write`**, the `print` magic will work (so `print >> f, [1,2,3,4]` would work, when `f.write([1,2,3,4])` wouldn't).

Comment: It's worth noting that this ``print`` syntax is exclusive to Python 2.x where ``print`` is a statement, it's different for 3.x where ``print()`` is a function.

Comment: @Lattyware Right, I added that!